vcpkg.json: select newest available major version
The vcpkg documentation has the following to say about how to constrain the version of a dependency in vcpkg.json:

version>=
Expresses a minimum version requirement, version>= declarations put a
lower boundary on the versions that can be used to satisfy a
dependency.
Note: vcpkg selects the lowest version that matches all constraints,
so a less-than constraint is not required.

The note does not make any sense to me. What you'd normally want is a combination of e.g. >=1.10.0 and <2.0.0 so vcpk downloads the newest available package without switching to a new major version with breaking changes. However, the documentation implies that you can only specify >=1.10.0 which would permanently pin the version to 1.10.0 even if e.g. 1.10.1 becomes available.
Am I understanding this correctly? What is the point of this? Is there a workaround?

Yes, you do understand this correctly. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/versioning.concepts


Am I understanding this correctly? What is the point of this? Is there a workaround?

No you are missing the baseline. If the baseline has version 1.15.0 you'll get 1.15.0. If you want to go below the baseline you need to use overrides. So if the baseline is 2.5.0 you'll get that unless you overrride it. However if your baseline is at 1.8.0 you'll get 1.10.0.
